# Jquery not loading for Ajax request, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some simple jquery that runs, and i want it to run with some ajax requests that im calling...but jquery isnt working in any of the ajax requests.

Here's the jquery plugin im using:

http://fancybox.net/

I'm calling the fancybox plugin like this:

`<a href="http://5.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/141,acer_aspire_s3.jpg" class="mybox" >`

Now that part works fine. I can have multiple of those links and all of them will load the fancy box Jquery plugin fine.

The issue is when i try to load those kind of data via a ajax request:

```
function ajaxTest(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

                        var txt = ajaxRequest.responseText;

            document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML = txt ;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/test/test.html", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

test.html is basically the same link as above, with class mybox...the only difference is that it doesnt load the jquery..it doesnt even register them...any help?

thanks

Comment: You don't need to use straight HTML in your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Please format your question properly, strip out those &nbsp's, etc.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, why not use it for the AJAX too?

Comment: please make your question clearer , so we can help .

Comment: sorry didnt realize it came out all wrong. apologies

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the binding is not happening at the correct time.

Try using [jQuery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind your events

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to take care of all that AJAX mess:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/test.html",
    success: function(response) {
      // here you can use "response"
    }  
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! def cleaned up ALOT better :D.